# Como llenar un select con el resultado de AJAX. PHP

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente ajax:

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: base_url + "rrhh/recibosueldo/mesesconRecibosEmpleados/" + select_id,
              data: select_id,
              success: function(data)
              {
                console.log(data);
              }
          });
```

que me trae como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la captura, En el select que esta vacio, deseo colocar lo que me trae (console.log) el ajax en "KEY" y Det.

Tambien deberia de ser con el formato correspondiente... Como este:

```
<option value="<?php echo substr($meses['Key'],0,6); ?>"><?php echo substr($meses['Det'],-7); ?></option>
```

EDIT: el HTML donde esta el select que quiero llena con los datos que trae el ajax es el siguiente:

```
<select id="mes" name="mes" class="form-control colorNaranja" style="display:inline; width:25%">
                    </select>
```

Comment: https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes un div en tu html que se llama "mi-div" donde irá el select:

```
<div id="mi-div"></div>
```

y nombras el select con el id "select-data", puedes construir el html de los datos así.

```
const data = [
  {"Key": "20211200447","Det": "MENSUAL 12/2021"},
  {"Key": "20211100777","Det": "MENSUAL 11/2021"}
];

let select_elem = document.createElement("select");
select_elem.setAttribute("id","select-data");

data.forEach( (obj) => {
  let elem = document.createElement("option");
  elem.value = obj["Key"].substring(0,6);
  elem.text = obj["Det"].substring(obj["Det"].length-7);
  select_elem.add(elem);
})

const d = document.getElementById("mi-div");
d.appendChild(select_elem);
```

En realidad, el elemento que quieres construir está en la variable select_elem.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho tu rta!